# How to call component method from slot - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vue and have problem with Vue `slots`. I have my component like this

```
<template>
<div class="dropDown__container">
  <div
    v-show="isOpened"
    class="dropDown__content"
    style="display:none;"
  >
    <slot />
    <div class="dropDown__container-flex">
      <span
        class="dropDown__button"
        @click="hideDropDown()"
      >
        Clear
      </span>
      <span
        class="dropDown__button"
        @click="hideDropDown(true)"
      >
        Submit
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a method `hideDropdown` which I would like to pass to my `slot`. For your inforamtion I am using this `slot` like this

```
<drop-down>
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <ul id="priceFromList" class="hintList hintList--left">
        <li class="hintList__item" v-for="price in lessThan(autocompletePricesDesktop, editableCriteria.Price.To)" @click="">
            {{ price }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</drop-down>
```

What I want to achieve is to pass `hideDropdown` method from component to `slot` and use it on `@click` for each `li`. Is this possible ? I will apprecaite any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> The below code syntax is only useable from vue 2.6

Well you can actually achieve it. I am not sure if it's best practice. Here is how you can achieve it.

In your Parent component will bind the function to the slot
`<slot :callableFunc="hideDropDown"/>`

```
  <template>
    <div class="dropDown__container">
      <div
        v-show="isOpened"
        class="dropDown__content"
        style="display:none;"
      >
        <slot :callableFunc="hideDropDown"/>
        <div class="dropDown__container-flex">
          <span
            class="dropDown__button"
            @click="hideDropDown()"
          >
            Clear
          </span>
          <span
            class="dropDown__button"
            @click="hideDropDown(true)"
          >
            Submit
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template
```

In your child component you will utilize scoped-slots to access the binded function.

```
<drop-down>
<template v-slot:default="{ callableFunc}">
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
    <ul id="priceFromList" class="hintList hintList--left">
        <li class="hintList__item" v-for="price in lessThan(autocompletePricesDesktop, editableCriteria.Price.To)" @click="callableFunc()">
            {{ price }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>
</drop-down>
```

Please take a look at the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to separate concerns, the dropdown-container should be the one deciding when to close the dropdown, and the slot-contained component should emit an event that can be used to indicate that something has happened, for example, that an item has been selected.

I would make the container listen to an event on the slot:
`<slot v-on:item-selection="itemSelected" />`

... and a function to receive the selected value:

```
function itemSelected(price) {
  this.price = price;
  hideDropdown();
}
```

In this case, the event is called `item-selection`.

Then I would emit that event the contained component: 
`<li class="hintList__item" v-for="price in lessThan(autocompletePricesDesktop, editableCriteria.Price.To)" @click="itemClicked(price)">`

... and a method in that component:

```
itemClicked(price) {
    this.$emit('item-selection', price);
}
```

I hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't make sense to me :(

Comment: Then maybe you would be better off refactoring the code to not use slots. Also, a discussion about using events and slots can be read here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4781

Comment: I have to use `slot` because part which is inside `slot` is made with ASP.NET Razor syntax so it is not a vue component

Comment: Okay, so in that case the scope is outside Vue, I think. I would implement a `created` hook on the container component and pass a reference to the click handling function to a global windows property: `window.onDropDownClicked = this.hideDropdown.` or something. But how would you retrieve the selection?

Comment: hmm, I understood only part about implementing `created` hook, could you please say something more or provide some example code ?